# Help me understand the meaning of this question about sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

From this [probability book](https://eng.uok.ac.ir/mfathi/Courses/Stochastic%20Process/ebooksclub.org__Probability_and_Random_Processes_for_Electrical_and_Computer_Engineers.pdf) page 50, question 13.

Let $X$ be any set and let $A \subset X$. Define the real valued function $f$ by

$$
f(x) := 
\begin{cases}
1, x\in A \\
0, x\notin A
\end{cases}
$$

Thus, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}:= (-\infty, \infty)$ denotes real numbers. For any arbitrary $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ find $f^{-1}(B)$. Hint: There are four cases to consider depending on if 0 or 1 belong to $B$.

What I don't understand about this question is the part where it says that $f(x)$ either returns a 1 or a 0 depending on the membership to the set $A$ but it then states in the next line that the output is the whole real line. I must be reading something wrong, how is this possible?

Comment: The notation $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is usually used to mean the function's range is a (possibly proper) subset of $\Bbb R$, not that the function's range is all of $\Bbb R$.  That's useful in case you want to do further real-valued manipulations of the output of the function $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide: The $4$ cases are

- $1 \in B$, $0 \in B$.
- $1 \in B$, $0 \notin B$.
- $1 \notin B$, $0 \in B$.
- $1 \notin B$, $0 \notin B$.

Evaluate the set for each case.

It is possible that $B$ contain elements other than $0$ and $1$, of which these elements will be ignored in this particular computation.

For example $f^{-1}(\{0,1,2\})=f^{-1}(\{0,1\})$ for our $f$.

$$f^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X:f(x) \in B\}$$